# including a text file in a structure in c

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

There is a structure which includes a text file.

```
struct student
{
  #include "test"
};
```

and the `test` is a plain ASCII text file with the following information

```
UU2(testing,value,21);
```

I am not sure what does it mean and what benefit we will get by including a text file in a structure.

Can anybody please help me on this?

Comment: It is very difficult to know what it means. You will need to find what UU2 is somewhere in your other files. You may try with something like `grep -r '#define.*UU2' ./include/` if you use Linux.

Comment: Even am not sure about what is UU2 and the OS am using is LINUX

Comment: While looking around I found that UU2 is a macro defined in some other file

Comment: `UU2` is probably a macro. `#include` and other preprocessor directives can be placed anywhere on their own line; the preprocessor doesn't know about the underlying C syntax and resolves macros and includes before the C compiler sees the code. Many compilers have a flag that allow you to see the preprocessed source code,e.g. `gcc -E stuff.c`.

Comment: One possible reason for storing struct bodies in external files is that your build process could automatically create `"test"` according to some settings.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind.  Such method of invoking the macro increasing the 'coupling' between files, which is a bad thing.  'coupling' between files makes debug, maintenance, etc much harder and makes the code more difficult to understand,

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for sure what is happening here, without context or a definition for `UU2`, but this looks a lot like the common C pattern known as [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). Normally there'd be more lines in the included file.

X macros serve to reverse the relationship between operator and operand (i.e. between macro and data). With a normal macro, the relationship is *one definition* -> *multiple inputs*, i.e. `#define M()...` will be followed by `M(foo)`, `M(bar)`, etc. throughout the code; one `M` operation is repeatedly applied to multiple different inputs.

In contrast, an X macro has the relationship *multiple definitions* -> *one input*. The input is expressed as a block of macro invocations, and then the surrounding code goes about setting suitable definitions for the macros so that those applications expand into something useful. This has the advantage that the same block of invocations can be repeatedly pasted into different contexts within the program where different definitions for its controlling macros have been set up, to create different expansions of the same basic input data. e.g. the same input block (in "block.x"):

```
M(one, 7);
M(two, 8);
M(three, 9);
```

...could be interpreted as a structure declaration, a structure initialization, or an unrolled loop over the elements of a structure, depending on the context it's placed and the visible definition of `M` at that point:

```
// context 1: declare a struct
#define M(N, V) int N;
struct foo {
    #include "block.x"
};

// context 2: initialize a struct
#define M(N, V) .N = V,
struct foo f = {
    #include "block.x"
};

// context 3: do something to a struct
#define M(N, V) if(THIS.N==8)puts("eight!");else puts("not eight");
#include "block.x"  // prints "not eight", "eight!", "not eight"
```

Putting the block of macro statements in its own file allows it to be easily `#include`d into multiple different expansion contexts, allowing a *single* structured data definition to have multiple applications. Centralizing the common structure in one file can help maintainability, by immediately propagating any changes in the structure of the data through to the way it's interpreted everywhere in the program.

(`#include` isn't the only way to do this, but it is the common pattern)

Why is this patten being used *here*, seemingly with only one line and only one definition for `UU2`? Well, the same principle can still apply - even though the program isn't currently applying the structured data in multiple locations, it still means that whatever process/person is generating it *doesn't need to know* anything about how the C program interprets the purely abstract structure they're supplying to it. They can focus on the layout only, and not need to know that it forms part of a type definition and how to edit that into a source file (or that C has such things as type definitions, or even that the program is written in C). They provide abstract structure and value, and the C program will impose its own meaning on the data.